# The formal version of "謝謝", "對不起", especially in an email?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, culture, formal

In English, when writing a formal email, one would sometimes use `appreciate/grateful` and `apologize` in place of `thank you` and `sorry`, respectively. Is there any such alternate words/phrases in Chinese for `謝謝` and `對不起`?

For instance, how can the following be rephrased in a formal tone?

> 對不起現在才回覆您。
>
> 謝謝您的幫助！

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alter words:

谢谢：多谢，感谢，谢恩（古代臣子百姓对君王说的）

对不起：抱歉，有愧，歉仄

As your case,

對不起現在才回覆您。

謝謝你的幫助！

rephrase:

（非常）抱歉现在才回复您。

（十分）感谢您的帮助！

Comment: 谢恩（古代臣子百姓对君王说的） and 歉仄 are really seldom used now. Maybe these should be omitted to prevent misinterpreting or abusing.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `您` in `謝謝你的幫助！`, not `你`

That will be more polite

Answer (score 2):

You can write `非常感谢...但很抱歉...`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the above answers are right. If you want to be VERY FORMAL in a written letter, you can use ancient expressions. Taiwanese still use them nowadays in formal letters.

Ancient ways to express gratitude in written letter:

承蒙关注，特此感谢。承蒙关照，不胜感激。请接受我的谢忱。费神之处，不胜感激，来示读悉；十分感谢。厚情盛意，应接不遑，切谢切谢。劳神为谢。费神之处，泥首以谢。感荷高情，非言语所能鸣谢。承赐忠言，心感何极。承蒙谆谆忠告，铭感铭感。承蒙见教，获益甚多。承示诚挚之言，佩其感甚。顷得惠函并照片种种，感谢之至。备荷关照，铭五内。承蒙惠赠，忠心感谢。前承馈赠……，倾感不胜。承蒙存问，不胜感谢；如此厚赠，实深惶涑。日前既荷盛钱，复蒙躬送，感谢无既。

Ancient ways to express apology in written letter:

惠书敬悉，甚感盛意，迟复为歉。惠书已悉，因为琐务，未即奉答为歉。久未通信，甚以为歉。久稽回答，幸原谅之。奉读惠书，久未作复，甚以为歉；数奉台函，未暇修复，抱歉良深。音问久疏，实深歉疚。惠书早日收到，因事纷繁，迟至今日奉复，甚歉。所询之事，目前尚难奉复。关于……之事，一时无以奉闻，歉甚。托付之事，未能尽如人意，尚请多多包涵。前言……，因事繁忘却，歉甚愧甚。杂务缠身，故托付之事延误至今方作复，歉甚。疏失之处，请少垂宽恕之情。前事有负雅意，十分抱歉，尚希恕之。前事有逆尊意，不胜惭愧，万望海涵。

However, these are not supposed to be used in speaking.